# how to write data to a h5py dataset

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

I'm going crazy here - for some reason, I can't find out how to change a dataset in h5py.
I first create a file:

```
i = h.File('C:\\Users\Bob\Desktop\blob.h5','w')
```

I then create a dataset within the file:

```
i.create_dataset("data",(100,100,100))
```

Finally, I try to write to the dataset:

```
i['data'][0][0][0] = 5
```

However, when I print, I don't get 5 back!

```
print(i['data'][0][0][0])#returns 0
```

I tried closing and reopening the file, but that didn't help.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, I haven't been able to find a way to mutate the contents of a dataset, but here's how to successfully create a new dataset.
First, store the data in a list (this could be a multi-dimensional numpy array instead):

```
l = [1,2,3]
```

Then, create the dataset:

```
i.create_dataset("array", data=l) 
arr = i["array"]
```

`print(arr[1])`
  will now correctly display the value 2

Answer (score 0):

Change the file mode argument for h5py.File from `w` to `r+` for read/write or `a` for read/write/create. See https://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/high/file.html